# Fixing the height of frame with resizing the window

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

how to fix the height of option frame with resizing the window?

I have 3 classes **`A`** ( a **`Frame`** ), **`B`** ( a **`Canvas`** ) and **`C`** ( an object ) `C` is top level.

In class `C`, I initialise the `A` by **`A( master, self )`** and **`.config( height = 40 )`**.

In class `A`, I established 2 sub-frame to contain a check button and an entry box + option menu, both frame and code `height = 20`

When I run the code, it worked pretty well, but when I resize the window.

If I click the mouse and drag down, it works OK.

But if I click the mouse and drag upwards (to reduce the height), the frame will disappear ( first the height of frame will reduce until be 0 and then the height of canvas will be changed ).

If I click the mouse and drag down, this option frame will return again

Can you give me some idea to fix this behavior?

Comment: Would be great to post your current code, Zheng

Comment: sorry it's my assignment, if teacher find similar code on internet I wiil be marked 0

Comment: **You may want to know**, that StackOverflow community encourages to post high quality questions altogether with a so called **MVCE** -- a Minimum-Verifiable-Complete-Example -- so that contributing Community member can help you to trace the root cause of the problem and direct you towards high quality solution options. **You may want to re-edit your post** so as to show your respect to the said StackOverflow principle and still provide a code, that neatly emulates your problem code-structure so that it does not violate your other ethical commitments.